# How to fill empty space in RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, xml

I have a **RelativeLayout** as parent layout, that contains two views: a VideoView and a Custom view for my custom media controller. These two views fill some space of RelativeLayout and I want to fill the rest space by LinearLayout, as you can see in this picture:

[image]

and this is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"/>

    <com.example.arantik.test13.MyMediaController
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myMediaController"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoView"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/myMediaController">
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

The parent layout must be just RelativeLayout. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not you use LinearLayout in this case.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

    <com.example.arantik.test13.MyMediaController
        android:id="@+id/myMediaController"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Update**

If you want this in RelativeLayout then put `android:layout_below="@id/myMediaController"` on `LinearLayout`.

Comment: for some reasons I have to use RelativeLayout.

Comment: Yes that's it! by using android:layout_below="@id/myMediaController" on LinearLayout, the problem is solved. Thank you so much @Khemraj .

Answer (score 3):

Make your parent layout as a`LinearLayout` and

`android:orientation="vertical"`.
or
If you need parent layout as `Relative layout`. Add below code in your `Linear layout`.

`android:layout_below="@+id/myMediaController"`

Comment: The parent layout must be RelativeLayout.

Comment: see my answer @Arantik

Comment: Good understanding of RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thank you @Khemraj

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff">
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   >

    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
       />

</FrameLayout>

<com.example.arantik.test13.MyMediaController
    android:id="@+id/myMediaController"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="108dp" />



</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="366dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```